# Angular Material - ({status: 400, message: "validation errors",…} field Errors: [{codes: null, arguments: null ...)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to send data in back end but i have a validation error :

```
{status: 400, message: "validation error",…}
fieldErrors: [{codes: null, arguments: null, defaultMessage: "ne peut pas être vide", objectName: "NotBlank",…},…]
0: {codes: null, arguments: null, defaultMessage: "ne peut pas être vide", objectName: "NotBlank",…}
arguments: null
bindingFailure: false
code: null
codes: null
defaultMessage: "ne peut pas être vide"
field: "username"
objectName: "NotBlank"
rejectedValue: null
1: {codes: null, arguments: null, defaultMessage: "ne peut pas être vide", objectName: "NotBlank",…}
2: {codes: null, arguments: null, defaultMessage: "ne peut pas être vide", objectName: "NotBlank",…}
message: "validation error"
status: 400
```

This is my component.ts :

```
    import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
    import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn, Validators, NgForm } 
    from '@angular/forms';
    import { Subject, from } from 'rxjs';
    import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

    import { FuseConfigService } from '@fuse/services/config.service';
    import { fuseAnimations } from '@fuse/animations';
    import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';
    import { MyErrorStateMatcher } from 'app/helpers/MyErrorStateMatcher ';

    @Component({
    selector     : 'register',
    templateUrl  : './register.component.html',
    styleUrls    : ['./register.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    animations   : fuseAnimations
    })
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit
    {
    registerForm: FormGroup;
    matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
     isSuccessful = false;

    constructor(
        private _fuseConfigService: FuseConfigService,
        private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private authService: AuthService
    )
    {
        // Configure the layout
        this._fuseConfigService.config = {
            layout: {
                navbar   : {
                    hidden: true
                },
                toolbar  : {
                    hidden: false
                },
                footer   : {
                    hidden: true
                },
                sidepanel: {
                    hidden: true
                }
            }
        };

    }


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // @ Lifecycle hooks
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * On init
     */
    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            username           : ['', Validators.required],
            email          : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password       : ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }
     onSubmit() {

        this.authService.register(this.registerForm).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.isSuccessful = true;

          },
          err => {


          }
        );
      }
}
```

And This is my angular material page:

```
    <div id="register" fxLayout="column">

    <div id="register-form-wrapper" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">

        <div id="register-form" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{duration:'300ms',y:'100px'}}">

            <div class="logo">
                <img src="assets/images/logos/fuse.svg">
            </div>

            <div class="title">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</div>

            <form name="registerForm" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="username" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
                    <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
                    <mat-error>
                        Name is required
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="email" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
                    <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">mail</mat-icon>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
                        Email is required
                    </mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('email')">
                        Please enter a valid email address
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required>
                    <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">vpn_key</mat-icon>
                    <mat-error>
                        Password is required
                    </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="submit-button" aria-label="CREATE AN ACCOUNT"
                        [disabled]="registerForm.invalid">
                    CREATE AN ACCOUNT
                </button>
            </form>

            <div class="register" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                <span class="text">Already have an account?</span>
                <a class="link" [routerLink]="'/login'">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="isSuccessful">
                Your registration is successful!
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What does your implementation of the `this.authService.register` method look like?

Comment: The error says username is null. What is your question?

Comment: this.authService.register send data to service. i send data but field is null any help!!

Comment: you aren't  passing data correctly i think that's why. Just check my updated answer with relevant snippets. Hopefully it will work. Justy make sure the data to be passed in api its names are correct. I have put as is but you would know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a 400 error, which is for bad request. From your error i searched this

> "Bne peut pas être vide", which means cannot be empty

So you are clearly sending something empty I guess. Its saying about username being empty. If you are sending it but still getting the error then you must be sending it incorrectly. Check the api doc for params and their type.

**Update:**

your following code, it has no value , this just creates your form.

```
`this.registerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            username  : ['', Validators.required],
            email     : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
            password  : ['', Validators.required],
  });`
```

Send your data after getting form value

```
const body = {
  username: form.value.username,
    email:   form.value.email,
    password:  form.value.password,
}
```

Then your onSubmit(form)

```
this.authService.register(body).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.isSuccessful = true;

      },
      err => {
      }
 );
```

In your HTML pass form in onSubmit()

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)">
```

Comment: When you are submitting the form console log the data that you are sending, clearly it can have error maybe. Just console log to see if it is valid data.